# Why the context manager fails to execute when using the value returned from it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, contextmanager

I'm using a context manager to communicate with one of my servers. I've created a context manager using the **contextlib** module:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def session_ctx(self):
    """context manager session interface"""
    try:
        self.connect()
        yield self
    finally:
        self.disconnect()
```

Pretty simple. It returns **self** to the ctx. Now I'm used to use it with the *as variable* syntax, `with obj.session_ctx() as s:`

```
with obj.session_ctx() as x:
     some_data = x.get_data()
     ...
```

This let's me work on the object returned from the context manager function.
However, this fails to execute `x.get_data()` with returns invalid state (such no connection exist).

If I remove the `as x` part and use the `obj` directly, it works as expected:

```
with obj.session_ctx():
    some_data = obj.get_data()
```

> Why don't this work with the *as x* ? If *x* is actually *self* of obj, this should be transparent, isn't it?

I'm using ctx on other parts of my code, and it seems to work with the `as x` syntax. I'm just curious why this is different.

**update:** I added debug prints, and *x* is assigned with the value returned from `self.connect()`. That's totally a different object. How is this changed??

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  I wrote a dummy class with methods that just print messages and added your context manager method, and `with obj.session_ctx() as x:` works just fine.

Comment: @jwodder thanks for trying, are you using python 2.7?

Comment: Yes, Python 2.7.12 on Ubuntu 16.04.3.